# Every time I reboot my Windows 10 machine, I have to restart the iSCSI service

Tags: windows-10, iscsi

Whenever I reboot, the iSCSI drives are not connected, and I see "reconnecting" in the Microsoft iSCSI initiator, if I try to disconnect I get an error, but after restarting the iSCSI service (at this point I've written a short powershell script and put it on my desktop), the iSCSI drives reconnect.

Someone recommended removing all the portals and adding them without using "quick connect" this did not seem to help.

The iSCSI server is a FreeNAS device and it has 1 portal with 1 target and 2 extents. It used to have 2 targets with one extent each, but I combined the 2 targets into one.

I've thought about just creating a scheduled task to restart the iSCSI service when I login, but I feel like I will probably still have to recreate the Steam Library on the drive every time.

The following bits of the story are much less relevant, but may hold clues:

I have a Windows 10 gaming PC with zero hard drives and several SATA SSDs (I can break it down if this matters, but the bottom line is I'm out of SATA ports on my motherboard)

Instead of installing hard drives for "slow storage", or using SMB (which is quite slow), I have 2 iSCSI drives (same target/portal, 2 different extents) coming from my NAS.

For awhile this "just worked", I got a 1TB m.2 SATA SSD and an adapter on Black Friday 2018 and that filled up my last SATA port.

The problems started more recently when I got a built-in USB3 hub that goes into the 5.25in bay... after installing it, both my new 1TB SSD and my iSCSI drives suddenly stopped working. I worked through this. The PCIe to M.2 adapter had come loose and the screw holding it in place was not working, so I replaced the screw, and ran chkdsk, etc. and all was well. But... somehow this messed up iSCSI? it's not clear, but it happened at the same time. Unless the game "The Talos Principal" (installed on the 1TB SSD), could have messed it up. (I had a fun crash when the SSD came loose, but again, not super relevant to the iSCSI problems)

I changed the iSCSI settings on my NAS to have 1 portal + 1 target with 2 extents instead of 1 portal with 2 targets (one extent on each target). This confused the hell out of Windows, I mostly did it because it seemed cleaner, but I was able to turn off the iSCSI service, uninstall the driver, nuke the iSCSI settings from the registry, and re-add everything, and everything seemed good.

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/808804/delaying-iscsi-target-service-startup

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up creating a schedule task which starts the iSCSI service, but delays until the network is ready (similar solutions recommended delaying for one minute).

Then I set Steam to start 90s after login instead of on login...

It's not ideal, but I restart my computer... and then go get coffee or whatever, and I come back and I can play games on my iSCSI drive without fiddling with settings.

The scheduled task looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2016-03-11T17:58:47.9924646</Date>
    <Author>gkmachine</Author>
    <URI>\Start iSCSI service at startup delayed</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <BootTrigger>
      <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT10M</ExecutionTimeLimit>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </BootTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-18</UserId>
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>true</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT72H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
    <RestartOnFailure>
      <Interval>PT5M</Interval>
      <Count>999</Count>
    </RestartOnFailure>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>powershell</Command>
      <Arguments>"-Command" "Restart-Service -Name 'Microsoft iSCSI Initiator Service'"</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

I used Glary Utilities to delay the startup of "Steam Client Bootstrapper" by 90 seconds, but probably you could remove the startup app, and set a scheduled task as well, instead of installing a weird helper utility (I like Glary though, and keep it around).